# How to import Json file from Feeds module

Tags: 8, feeds, importing-exporting

I am using Feeds import module with Feeds extensible parsers module, I am getting following error. I am not getting what is wrong with the json and settings. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance,

[image]

My json look like,

[
{
"lcia_id": ,
"name": "",
"company_name": "",
"company_id": ,
"net_weight": ,
"country": "",
"address": "--",
"serving_size": "-",
"composition": [],
"type": "",
"field_ingredientimpactcarboningm": ,
"field_ingredientaggimpactbiosli": ,
"field_ingredientaggimpactwaterle": ,
"field_ingredientaggimpactwaterpo": ,
"field_processingimpactcarboningm":
},
]

and in Feeds setting I have used,

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a value for the `lcia_id` key.

In your Feeds Type mapping, we can see that the entity's `ID (nid)` is mapped to the JSON file's `lcia_id`, but, in your sample JSON file, the `lcia_id` value is missing.

You could also consider using [Feeds Tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) to set a default value when no value is available for `lcia_id`. [Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2287473) is an example of how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its work. but now, the problem is I cann't mapping feed with a reference field. How to use feeds with entity reference?

Comment: The 'lcia_id' is a reference id in json like 
      {
        "lcia_id": 6,
        "composition": 0.04975124378109454
      }
How should we map?